# load jquery before elements on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i load jquery before all the html elements to stop unstyled content flashing before jquery kicks in.

I know you can do this with `display:none` in the css but I would like to know how to do it in an accesible way.

heres an example

http://satbulsara.com/tests/

Comment: It's not up to you.... the browser usually does load JS before the elements but until the elements exist jQuery can't really do anything..

Comment: Could you rephrase your question in order to make it more clear what you are trying to do? If you want to load jQuery before the elements on the page, simply including it in the `<head>` of your document should suffice...

Comment: hmmmm, yeah i just wanted to stop the content image loading before the fadin effect happens without using display:none in css

Comment: you can't really do that, the fade effect can't work before the image exist and is loaded.

Comment: Actually you can set the image CSS properties (via JS) before the file is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this guy's advice with a nice `fadeIn()` effect to great satisfaction: [1 Way to Avoid the Flash of Unstyled content](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/10/1-way-to-avoid-the-flash-of-unstyled-content)

Comment: nice 1!! I followed this before but added the

Comment: $('html').addClass('js'); in the doc ready like an idiot. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a very small javascript file in the head, which only sets `visibility: hidden` to the relevant elements, and comes before jquery.

Of course you will have to use the DOM directly

```
document.getElementById('someImage').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I think you're looking for a preloader? I've used this one before with great results:
http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/